# Parse.com Weekly Active Users, Converting the JSON database to .csv for analysis

Tags: python, json, parse-platform, analytics

I don't know how to use Parse so I'm open to all ideas. I want to analyze how many weekly active users we have, and would also like to perform "cohort analysis" ie track analytics between two distinct types of users. (like which month they downloaded, how long do they keep the app installed etc).

My main question is, how can I analyze the data that parse spits out? I exported the data and it comes in a JSON file. What do I do with this? I was hoping it would be a .csv file that I could analyze in Matlab or with Python or VBA.

Any guidance would help, I don't know what to do with json files haha

Comment: Well, you could ingest the JSON with `json.load`, read information from it, then use `csv` to write it to a csv file, if that's what you really want. You could probably also export directly to `pandas` to do the heavy lifting for data analytics

Answer (score 0):

A great way to start is by familiarizing yourself with JSON by heading over to its official resource page at http://www.json.org/. Once you get your JavaScript Object Notation legs on, then proceed to use json.load as inspectorG4dget recommended.